# Mathematica ignores my assumption when solving a qudratic equation

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

I try to solve the inequality $r-3t_0-2\sqrt{2 rt_0}<0$ with assumption that $0\leq r\leq 2t_0$. First, by observation, we can clearly see that if $r=0$, then clearly, this inequality holds. Then I use mathematica

```
Assuming[{t0 >= 0, r >= 0, r < 2*t0}, Simplify[Solve[r - 3*t0 - 2*Sqrt[2*r*t0] == 0, r]]]
```

The output is

```
(* Out: {{r -> (7 - 2 Sqrt[10]) t0}, {r -> (7 + 2 Sqrt[10]) t0}} *)
```

which is $r_1=(7-2\sqrt{10})t_0$ (which is positive) and $r_2=(7+2\sqrt{10})t_0$. This means, if $r_1<r<r_2$, then $r-3t_0-2\sqrt{2rt_0}<0$ will be true. But clearly $r=0$ will make $r-3t_0-2\sqrt{2rt_0}<0$ also true. Also, I feel that $(r-r_1)(r-r_2)$ does not give back my $r-3t_0-2\sqrt{2rt_0}$. Do I miss something?

Comment: Have you tried `Reduce` ?  `Reduce[r - 3 t0 - 2 Sqrt[2 r t0] < 0, r, Reals]`

Comment: @JimB it gives '(t0 <= 0 && r < 7 t0 + 2 Sqrt[10] Sqrt[t0^2]) || (t0 > 0 && 
   0 <= r < 7 t0 + 2 Sqrt[10] Sqrt[t0^2])', which still does not make any sense. I don't think $r=7t_0+2\sqrt{10}t_0$ is a correct root

Comment: [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) function is only appending to [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html), which is default value of [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) option for most functions that use it. `Solve` function does not have `Assumptions` option, so yes it *is* ignoring your assumptions, which might be surprising, but it is the documented behavior.

Comment: For functions like `Solve` and `Reduce`, that don't take `Assumptions` option, assumptions should be put in logical conjunction in first argument. `Reduce[r - 3*t0 - 2*Sqrt[2 r t0] < 0 && 0 <= r < 2 t0] (* t0 > 0 && 0 <= r < 2 t0 *)`